# How I can update array field value in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

```
isMain = (v, k) => {

    let {avatars: {fields}, push} = this.props;

    fields.getAll().map((avatar, key) => {

      fields.remove(key);

      push('avatars', {
        deleteImage: avatar.deleteImage || false,
        uuid: avatar.uuid,
        fileName: avatar.fileName,
        url: avatar.url,
        setMain: key === k,
      });

    });

};
```

This is how I try^ 
Doesn't work, I don't know why

I use v6

I also tried **insert**

But with **insert** field not removed only - copied! 
Although the value of new fields changed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you only want to update a single item in array `avatars`, an alternative solution is using redux-form's [Action Creators](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/). Just need to provide the index value to action:

```
import { change } from 'redux-form'
...
setMain: (k) => dispatch(change(`yourForm`, `avatars[${k}].setMain`, true))
```

You can create another action `removeMain(k)` in the same manner to remove the old main avatar item.

Comment: I can't import the `change` function, while I can import the others just fine (`Field, Fields, formValueSelector`). It shows this error:
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redux-form/es/change'`